# Apache - Ubuntu Server - Redirect HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, ssl

I am trying to redirect all http to https. 
I have added a `.htaccess` file to my root folder `var/www/html/` using:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
</IfModule>
```

However, this code is not working and the page still showing http connection.

My web site is working fine using https. How can redirect my site to ssl connection? Do I have to restart apache?

Comment: **1)** Make sure you've enabled `mod_rewrite` (if not do it then restart your server). **2)** Check that htaccess files are allowed (Apache config file -> `AllowOverride` set to `All` for concerned block). **3)** Make sure `/var/www/html/` is the document root folder for your `http` version

Comment: 1) Module rewrite already enabled

Comment: Thank you Justin, just added  `<Directory /var/www/>
 Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
 AllowOverride All
 Require all granted
</Directory>` and I think its working now

Comment: if I try to open `http://example.com/phpmyadmin/` its not redirected

Comment: If the hostnames match the rewrite will be internal without the `[R,L]` flags. Also see [this](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteHTTPToHTTPS)